# How to select file to copy based on Docker environment variable?

Tags: javascript, docker, dockerfile

My problem is that I have some URLs hard coded in a Javascript file. They are specific to the environment where I deploy my docker image. Here is a example of the different urls I need to have.

For the `live ENV`:

```
export const BLUE_SERVICE   = 'https://myliveserver/api/blueservice';
export const RED_SERVICE    = 'https://myliveserver/api/redservice';
```

For the `release ENV`:

```
export const BLUE_SERVICE   = 'https://myreleaseserver/api/blueservice';
export const RED_SERVICE    = 'https://myreleaseserver/api/redservice';
```

My idea was to have two versions of the file. I would then copy one or the other based on an `ENV VARIABLE` in my dockerfile. By the way I already have a `ENV VARIABLE` called `STAGE`

Perhaps there is an other (better) solution to do this. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [build-time variables](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables-build-arg) instead:

```
docker run –-build-arg BLUE_SERVICE='...' –-build-arg RED_SERVICE='...'
```

> This flag allows you to pass the build-time variables that are accessed like regular environment variables in the `RUN` instruction of the Dockerfile.
>   Also, these values don’t persist in the intermediate or final images like `ENV` values do.

You could generate two images which would, in their Dockerfile, generate the right javascript file using the right value for BLUE and RED SERVICE.